# Does excess whitespaces and new lines make PHP code run slower?

Tags: php, execution-time

For me it's more comfortable to write

```
<?php

$a = true;

if(true) {

    $a = false;

}

?>
```

Would next code executes faster:

```
<?php
$a = true;
if(true) {
    $a = false;
}
?>
```

**UPD**

Even if whitespace characters are ignored by PHP, while parsing .php file PHP should think ("should I ignore this character or not") every time it encounters whitespace. Would it increase execution time or not?

Comment: this reminds me of `minified` javascript http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minification_%28programming%29

Comment: Only if you use whitespace to dehydrate and hydrate code to obsfuscate it :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Extra whitespace will have next to no effect on performance, other than technically there are more characters to crawl over at parse time.  We're talking about fractions of fractions of a second here, because the whitespace is simply ignored as it's parsed.

Also with OPCODE caching like [APC](http://php.net/manual/en/book.apc.php), subsequent requests for the same file will not incur re-parsing of the same file (generally speaking).

Comment: While we're on the subject.., if anyone wants some trivial pursuit cred, take a peak at `php -w` on the command line ;)

Answer (score 2):

No, not really.

All whitespaces are ignored by bytecode parser, and if you are running any kind of accelerator (xcache,apc,etc) your code is actually runned from bytecode cache not file.

Comment: They are ignored, but must still be crawled over by the parser; therefore technically, there is some overhead, though incredibly minute.

Comment: But how often is parser actually being runned? Most apps use APC, XCache or something similar where application is being runned from bytecode cache not code itself ..

Comment: Right, that's *IFF* you're running APC.  Also, in order for the file to be cached it must be parsed, and those white spaces must be read before they can be ignored.

Answer (score 1):

No, it would not be noticeably (and probably not even measurably) faster at all. Maybe if you have pages and pages of whitespace in between each line of code, you would see a difference. But in general no, there is no performance improvement.

Answer (score 0):

The whitespaces are not parsed by PHP.